# Ampersand between arguments in PHP

Tags: php

In this [User Contributed Note](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) at php.net there is a function called like this:

```
FriendlyErrorType($errLvl & pow(2, $i))
```

I know that the ampersand can be used to pass an argument to a function by reference but that does not seem to be what is happening here although maybe it is and I can't understand it.

What is the ampersand doing in this case?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: In case it is not obvious, it is doing an AND operation between $errLv1 variable and the result of the function pow.  It is not passing by reference as pow is a function, not a variable.  It does not have a $ in front of it.